# How to make Animated Web Speech API UI in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, webspeech-api

I have to create a **animation Like [Google.com Dekstop](https://google.com) Mic shows** (i.e. scaling of the mic border according to the loudness of voice). I have used the *Web Speech API* with reference from [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) which shows how we can change the background colour of the webpage using our voice, it work's fine but I want to add Animation Like **Google's site**( mentioned above).
*I have searched a lot to find a way to achieve this animation but I was unable to find this*. So I am asking here as this is the best place where I can get my answer **:)**
 Thanks a lot in advance for helping me out with this.

Comment: I'm not sure the volume indication can use the speech recognition API, but you can run 2 process in parallel. MDN has a nice example of volume indication by using audio analyzer -> [`frequencyBinCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/maxDecibels#example)

Comment: So how can I make the same animation just like Google?? Can you please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not expert in this area but I followed the example in MDN and here is the result.

Beside the setup, the key point here is [`analyser.getByteFrequencyData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) which gives us the decibel levels.

In order to simplify the code, I took the highest decibel level in the array (`Math.max.apply(null, dataArray)`) but you can fine tuning it by average or any other calculation you like.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vptrhr?devtoolsheight=33&file=script.js)

```js
let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let distortion = audioCtx.createWaveShaper();
let gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
let biquadFilter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
analyser.minDecibels = -90;
analyser.maxDecibels = -10;

analyser.fftSize = 256;

const mic = document.querySelector('.mic');
let isListening = false;
let tracks = [];

if (!navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  alert('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}

mic.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  if (!isListening) {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      isListening = true;

      tracks = stream.getTracks();
      source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      source.connect(distortion);
      distortion.connect(biquadFilter);
      biquadFilter.connect(gainNode);
      gainNode.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

      requestAnimationFrame(function log() {
        let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
        let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
        const level = Math.max.apply(null, dataArray);
        document.querySelector('#level span').textContent = level;
        mic.style.setProperty('--border', `${level / 5}px`);
        requestAnimationFrame(log);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('The following gUM error occured: ' + err);
    }
  } else {
    isListening = false;
    tracks.forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.mic {
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px var(--border) rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="mic">
        <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="level">Level: <span></span></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Just one problem is there when I turn on the mic in your demo it creates Noise and when I mute the pc speaker no more noise is present. What is the reason behind that can u please tell me?

Comment: Because there is always a background noise. When the mic is muted, the computer is ignoring every audio input it gets including the noises.