# Transition effect when button gets visible/invisible in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this app that upon going down 500px, a scroll to top button shows up and upon going back up, it disappears. But the effect of it is quick and there's no animation to it:

*JS*

```
const ScrollTop = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  // Show Button After Scrolling Down More than 500px
  const toggleVisible = () => {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > 500 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500
    ) {
      setVisible(true);
    } else {
      setVisible(false);
    }
  };

  // Listen for Scrolling Event
  window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleVisible);

  // Get Back Top when Clicked
  const handleScroll = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
    });
  };

  return (
    <button
      id="back-to-top"
      style={{ display: visible ? "block" : "none" }}
      onClick={handleScroll}
      title="Go To Top"
    >
      <i className="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </button>
  );
};
```

*CSS*

```
#back-to-top {
  background: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 51, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#back-to-top:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 140);
}
```

**Is there any way in CSS and JS to add a transition effect to its behavior so it'll smoothly fade in and out?**

Comment: You can Get Help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70331500/15546569), It can Help but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For styling I suggest conditionally applying a classname when you want to display the back-to-top button. You will also want to move the adding (***and removing***) of the window scroll listener into an `useEffect` hook. The `useEffect` hook should add the event listener and return a cleanup function to remove it when the `ScrollTop` component unmounts. Provide `false` as the third argument so you use passive listeners.

```
const ScrollTop = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  // Show Button After Scrolling Down More than 500px
  const toggleVisible = () => {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > 500 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500
    ) {
      setVisible(true);
    } else {
      setVisible(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for Scrolling Event
    window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleVisible, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", toggleVisible, false);
    }
  }, []);

  // Get Back Top when Clicked
  const handleScroll = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
    });
  };

  return (
    <button
      id="back-to-top"
      className={visible ? "back-to-top-visible" : null}
      onClick={handleScroll}
      title="Go To Top"
    >
      <i className="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    </button>
  );
};
```

CSS - How you want to transition is up to you, but the basic starting point is to define a `transition` rule with property/ies to transition, a duration, easing/timing function, and delay. For the example I chose to transition the scaling. Start with an initial scaling value of 0, and when the `back-to-top-visible` classname is applied end with a scaling value of 1.

[Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```
#back-to-top {
  background: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 51, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#back-to-top:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 140);
}

#back-to-top.back-to-top-visible {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

[image: Edit transition-effect-when-button-gets-visible-invisible-in-react]

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. But thanks for the hint about adding useEffect

Comment: @Nima It certainly works in the codesandbox I linked. Is the code you shared in your question not an accurate representation of your actual code and use case? Can you create a codesandbox that reproduces any issues you have that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: this is so weird. I copy/pasted the codesandbox you made and it totally works but when I try it, it doesn't. I'll compare them side by side now to see what I'm missing.

Comment: I also noticed that the toggleVisible function in your sandbox differs from mine. Is that achieving the same functionality?

Comment: I didn't notice that I had to remove that style attribute that changes the display. Now it works! I know display cannot work with transition yet your solution achieves what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Nima Yeah, the `toggleVisible` logic was just a little applied Boolean Zen. Also, sorry for not calling out needing to remove the `style` prop setting the `display` rule, it doesn't work with transitions.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry if this question is not that much relevant but you mentioned to add a "false" as the third argument of my listener to use it as passive. Is there any reason not to use {passive: true} in here instead of "false" that you mentioned?

Comment: @Nima Nope, either *should* work in most cases. Using the config object is newer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to target the button in your CSS and add transition like this:

```
#back-to-top {
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

or you can try this solution where you can conditionally render class.

**CSS:**

```
#back-to-top {
  background: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 51, 0);
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
}
.hide-class {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}

.show-class {
  opacity: 1;
}

#back-to-top:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 140);
}

import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./style.css";
```

**ScrollTop:**

```
const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  // Show Button After Scrolling Down More than 500px
  const toggleVisible = () => {
    if (
      document.body.scrollTop > 500 ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500
    ) {
      setVisible(true);
    } else {
      setVisible(false);
    }
  };

  // Listen for Scrolling Event
  window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleVisible);

  // Get Back Top when Clicked
  const handleScroll = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
    });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
    <button
      id="back-to-top"
      className={`${visible ? 'show-class': 'hide-class'}`}
      onClick={handleScroll}
      title="Go To Top"
    >
      Go to top
    </button>
      </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nnaxjj-scqda5?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Comment: @Nima try this solution